# Unity Console says "type or namespace definition, or end of file expected unity"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, inverse-kinematics

I'm making a VR test and I've run into a problem and am not sure what to do. Unity keeps saying "type or namespace definition, or end of file expected unity" I am using someone else's code but I am following the tutorial. Here is my code

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VrRig : MonoBehaviour { }

    public Transform headConstraint;
    public Vector3 headBodyOffset;

{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        headBodyOffset = transform.position - headConstraint.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = headConstraint.position + headBodyOffset;
            transform.forward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(headConstraint.up,Vector3.up).normalized;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a closing brace right after MonoBehavior and an opening brace before void Start(). You need to remove both of those.

Answer (score 3):

you are creating an empty class by having the curly brackets open and closed right after the class declaration. after you declare a code block with class members but never assign it to anything. If you put an opening curly bracket right after the class declaration and close it after all your members, it should work.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VrRig : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform headConstraint;
    public Vector3 headBodyOffset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        headBodyOffset = transform.position - headConstraint.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = headConstraint.position + headBodyOffset;
            transform.forward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(headConstraint.up,Vector3.up).normalized;
    }
}
```